# Tokenize a string using apache lucene

Tags: java, lucene

How to tokenize the string based on a patter?

Example. In following string

```
arg1:aaa,bbb AND arg2:ccc OR arg3:ddd,eee,fff
```

First I want to tokenize based on AND and OR

So

```
Token set 1 arg1:aaa,bbb

Token set 2 arg2:ccc

Token set 3 arg3:ddd,eee,fff
```

Later i want to pass these individual token sets to a method and tokenize based on ":"

```
Token set 1
Token 1 aaa
Token 2 bbb

Token set 2
Token 1 ccc

Token set 3
Token 1 ddd
Token 2 eee
Token 3 fff
```

How to tokenize using custom patter using Lucene?

Comment: Can't help but notice that your custom syntax looks rather like a Lucene query, barring the likely need for some parentheses.  Is there anything to that?  Or just incidental?

Comment: Nope. My App gets this form of string from a third party vendor. And it is their format and there are no parentheses. So i have no control on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a custom tokenization implementation, you would generally implement your own [`Tokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html).  The primary method that needs to be implemented would be [`TokenStream.incrementToken()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html#incrementToken%28%29).

Your `Tokenizer` can then be incorporated into an [`Analyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).

Comment: Yes. Implementing custom tokenizer was only option. There is no explicit library available.